# window installation with usb

Tags: usb, uefi

two days ago I bought samsung laptop 
I don't know Korea language 
Therefore I want to replace another window with English language
I want to replace new window 8.1 with usb but it cann't boot 
how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an .iso bootable on a USB use this programme:
http://www.isotousb.com

If you want to boot from the USB:

1. Go to your BIOS
2. Change the boot order to put your USB first
3. Save the changes and wait for it to reboot and run the installer.

Comment: how to change boot order 
if possible show me with figure

Comment: There are many different BIOS but try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/

Comment: I cann't change boot order How to do it?

Comment: You change your boot order on BIOS take an image of the first screen that you see when you turn it on. I will see if I can help you out

Comment: For boot\
Intially as show in fig
1) First I choose windows boot manager
   It continue the existing windows
2) therefore I choose Enter Setup
3)   but I can't change boot device priority
4)   cann't enable secure boot control